# How to create spacing between tabsetpanel and graph in shiny?

Tags: r, graph, shiny

I used the `tabsetpanel()` function to create tabs for two different graphs. However, I'm running into the problem where the title of the graph is really close to the tabs and there isn't any spacing. It looks like it's squished together, so I'm wondering how I can create spacing between the tab panel and the graph? I have a shiny widget on the left side that is controlling the graph on the right side. Here is an example of my code:

```
tabPanel("Name",
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       selectInput(
         <shiny widget coding is here>
       )
     ),
     mainPanel(
       tabsetPanel(
         tabPanel("graphname", plotlyOutput("graph1")),
         tabPanel("graphname2", plotlyOutput("graph2"))
       )
     )
   )
)
```

So as you can see there is the tabsetPanel and then the tabpanels that have the graph. But there's no spacing between the graphs and tabsetpanel bar, which looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty, using `br()` just before the plot. `br()` is a HTML-Linebreak:

```
library(shiny)    
library(plotly)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(tabPanel("Name",
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(

                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("graphname", br(), plotlyOutput("graph1")),
                      tabPanel("graphname2",  plotlyOutput("graph2"))
                    )
                  )
                )
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$graph1 <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(mtcars)%>% layout(title = "With Space")
    })

    output$graph2 <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(mtcars)%>% layout(title = "Without Space")
    })

  }
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put the graphs in a `fluidRow` and if that doesn't help. Add `style = "padding-top:20px"` as an argument to the `fluidRow`.

Answer (score -1):

```
tabPanel("graphname", br(), plotlyOutput("graph1"))
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: how is this different from the above answer of shosaco?